# DSOFILE nuget installing error - 'cannot add reference'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dll, reference

I'm trying to install the DSOFile nuget for geting properties of files using the nuget package bellow : https://www.nuget.org/packages/DSOFile/
I place the nupkg file in the private nuget server I have, and I can see the package in the "Manage Nuget Packages" window. Then I press install and then the following lines:

Installing 'DSOFile 2.1.0.2'

Successfully installed 'DSOFile 2.1.0.2'

Adding to 'DSOFile 2.1.0.2' to MyProject.

Uninstalling 'DSOFile 2.1.0.2'

Successfully uninstalled 'DSOFile 2.1.0.2'

Install failed . Rolling back...

Failed to add reference to 'dsofile'

*** The same happens when I create a nuget package on my own from the DSOFile.dll I have.

What is the problem?

Comment: Delete all the folders inside of the packages folder.

Comment: Didn't work, the same error @NahumLitvin

Answer (score 0):

This package is unlisted by owner. So you can't get it from Nuget.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/DSOFile/